# Get IDP params on my SP with PHP

Tags: php, apache, saml, adfs, shibboleth

I configured an SP server with Shibboleth and Apache. The communication with the IDP works, but I don't receive data after login on my SP.

I search on `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_SESSION`, and `$_SERVER`, but i don't get the IDP parameters on PHP.

When i visit the url "https://mydomain.ext/Shibboleth.sso/Session", the Attributes is empty.

I would like how to know receive parameters on PHP.

Thank's

Comment: Do you see a $_GET parameter called SAMLRequest or something similar?

Comment: Yes, i can see SAMLRequest by $_GET method in the referer URL. I think that i need SAMLResponse token, right?¿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shibboleth SP needs to be told to accept attributes. e.g. in

```
SHIBBOLETH_HOME/etc/shibboleth/attribute-map.xml

<Attribute name="urn:oid:0.0.7" id="CB_InterestingAttribute">
  <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="StringAttributeDecoder" caseSensitive="false"/>
</Attribute>
```

and in, for example, a Sinatra app you can access it via:

```
ENV['CB_InterestingAttribute']
```

Comment: Thank'u codebrane, i can see the attribute-map.xml file, but i don't know about edit this... I supposed that i need receive the next params => [see image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzMmPHSXV4dyMlNTZTdmSDlYRDRnbUdNS0xZNjZSZlcyUENj/view)

Comment: I normally edit file in vi (linux). If you're on Windows you could try a text editor. If you open it in a text editor you should see the above XML

Comment: hehe, yes.. i mean about how to include the attributes. I can see this attributes on idp federation xml file, and i copy&paste this attributes on my "attribute-map.xml" file. is it correct? thank's

Comment: that should be enough to let your SP use the attribute. If the IdP releases it.

Comment: i understand... do you know if "attribute-policy.xml" file can be to affect? i've it by default

Comment: Thank'u codebrane, when i set the attributes on my "attributes-map.xml" and request to IDP allow attributes for me, it works correctly. Only i needed the types of attributes to set correctly in my file.

Comment: is it working for you now? You can use attribute-map.xml to isolate your application from Shibboleth. e.g. if your application needs to know the 'username' of the user, you can add "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:eduPersonPrincipalName" with an id "username" to your attribute-map.xml and your app can then get it using ENV['username']